# Cocoa touch how to set label to NSDate

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, label, nsdate

I have a label called datelabel and I want to set it to a NSDate called dateofbirth in my AppDelgate.

I have defined and imported my AppDelgate and set it to appDelgate,but when I try `self.datelabel.text = appDelgate.dateofbirth`

But when I put that in it gives my this error `Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSString *' from 'NSDate *'`

I tried a few things but none of them worked.

Is there any way to set a label to a NSDate.

Comment: NSDateFormatter is your friend :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the `NSDate` to a `NSString`. You can use an `NSDateFormatter` for that.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
// you can use one of the builtin localizated formats
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
self.datelabel.text = [formatter stringFromDate:appDelgate.dateofbirth];
// or you can set your own format
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
self.datelabel.text = [formatter stringFromDate:appDelgate.dateofbirth];
```